# Cannot use existing network in Compose: ERROR: Network declared as external, but could not be found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, swarm

I'm trying to create a service that must join the existing stack, so I force the compose to use the same network.

Surely, my network is persists

```
 docker network ls
   NETWORK ID          NAME                             DRIVER              SCOPE
   oiaxfyeil72z        ELK_default                      overlay             swarm
   okhs1e1wu73y        ELK_elk                          overlay             swarm
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services: 
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.5.1
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    volumes:
      - '/share/elk/logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro'
      - '/share/elk/logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/:ro'
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
networks:
  elk:
    external: 
       name: ELK_elk
```

the other services was created with

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - '/share/elk/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro'
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    volumes:
      - '/share/elk/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro'
    networks:
      - elk
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

networks:
  elk:
    driver: overlay
```

check with docker stack services

```
docker stack services ELK
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                 PORTS
c0rux6mdvzq3        ELK_kibana          replicated          1/1                 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.1                 *:5601->5601/tcp
j824fd0blxdp        ELK_elasticsearch   replicated          1/1                 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1   *:9200->9200/tcp, *:9300->9300/tcp
```

Then trying to bring the service up with `docker-compose up -d`. The service doesn't create but produce the error

```
docker-compose up -d
WARNING: Some services (logstash) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Removing tmp_logstash_1
Recreating bbf503fc3eaa_tmp_logstash_1 ... error

ERROR: for bbf503fc3eaa_tmp_logstash_1  Cannot start service logstash: Could not attach to network ELK_elk: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = network ELK_elk not manually attachable

ERROR: for logstash  Cannot start service logstash: Could not attach to network ELK_elk: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = network ELK_elk not manually attachable
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason non manager nodes only see networks with active containers using it (Run on non manager node):

`docker run --rm -d --name dummy busybox # Run a dummy container`

`docker network connect [OVERLAY_NETWORK] dummy # Connect to overlay network`

now network is available on non manager node and you can run:

`docker compose -f compose.yaml -p project up -d`

`docker stop dummy # Remove dummy container`

Compose file:

```
networks:
  db:
    external: true
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the fact that the elk network is defined as an "overlay" network. It's a docker swarm feature so docker-compose does not know how to deal with it.

Instead of using `docker-compose up` you need to deploy a docker swarm stack:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <service_name>
```

You can refer to the Docker documentation for more info:
https://docs.docker.com/network/